# Large file upload

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, upload

Im building a MVC 5 app, where users can upload images. I ran into the filsize cap of 4mb. the solution I can read is to add this to web.config:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```

but when doing so, the site crashes with an configuration error:

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Removing the line and the site is running again.

Is there an alternative or workarround?

Comment: I'm guessing your config file already had an httpRunTime element somewhere.  If you add a second one, the config can't be properly parsed.

Comment: Check the "Config Error" section in the error page you are seeing ? It should give you a hint

Comment: Which IIS version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

For IIS7 or later, add this line to webconfig

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" /> <!--50MB-->
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Or open IIS GUI
[image]

Comment: Im developing on a IIS expers, and chaged it there, with no luck, then i deployd in IIS 7 , and changed in web.config, no luck and in UI, still no luck. Is there something im missing, since the changes are not reflected any where??